# Nginx "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, nginx

I am running a ruby application on Nginx. It is working fine on Apache. When I try to load the ruby application I get this error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" It fails to find two .json files. I had the same issue with Apache before. It was due to a typo of the document path in apache conf file.

This is my Nginx conf file within the server block.

```
#owums
location ~ ^/wifi(/.*|$) {
    alias /var/www/owums/public$1;  # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_base_uri /wifi;
    passenger_app_root /var/www/owums;
    passenger_document_root /var/www/owums/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env development;
}
```

This is my Apache conf file. When I comment out DocumentRoot /var/www/owums/public in Apache conf, Apache will throw the same error.

Any ideas?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /wifi /var/www/owums/public
   <Location /wifi>
        PassengerBaseURI /wifi
        PassengerAppRoot /var/www/owums
    </Location>
    RailsEnv production
    ServerName wifi
    DocumentRoot /var/www/owums/public
    <Directory /var/www/owums/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My Nginx server block listens on port 3000. root is /var/www.

Comment: As asked, this isn't a Ruby or Rails problem. If the code being run can't find the JSON files, then you need to show the code trying to load the files. My guess, which is all that can be given with the little you've told us, is that your paths aren't correct, so you'll need to diagnose that.

Comment: I guess is the Nginx path problem. But I don't know what else to do to solve it.